# $q.all in a then Clause

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

What is the correct way to use `$q.all` in a promise chain `then` clause?

Here is some pseudo-type code to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
function nestedPromise(val) 
{
    return aPromiseReturningFunction(val)
        .then($q.all(val.arrayProperty.map(function(anotherVal) 
        {
            return anotherPromiseReturningFunction({
                prop1: anotherVal.prop
            });
        })));
}
```

Expectation: if any of the promises returned in the call to `$q.all` reject, the promise returned by `nestedPromise` will reject.

Actual: the promise returned by `nestedPromise` is resolved, even though one of the promises returned in the call to `$q.all` rejected.

I can't post everything I have tried to get this to work because I feel like I have tried literally everything...`catch`es all over the place, using `deferred`, etc. I think at one point I got things "working" by using a ton of deferrals and `catch`es, but it was really ugly and it definitely didn't work because I knew what I was doing.

Is it expected behavior for all of the function calls in my `$q.all` call to run in parallel? That seems to be what is currently happening because even after one promise rejects, the remainder continue to run. For the time being, I can deal with this behavior although it doesn't seem quite right and I'd like to know how to halt execution after the first rejection is encountered.

Comment: `then` takes a function, I don't really know `$q` but it looks like you could just do: `val => $q.all(..)`. I can't really tell if you expect the `val` inside the `$q.all` to be the same as the parameter of the `nestedPromise` function or the resolved value of the promise.

Comment: To the `then` function, pass a function that returns `$q.all(/* ... */)`, i.e. a promise.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @LoremIpsum! So you're saying break the `$q.all` piece out into a separate function and call that in my `then`? What about that is functionally different than what I am doing?

Comment: @MinusFour - in this case, my intention is that `val` always points to the value passed into the outermost function. Your suggestion (`val => $q.all(...)`) would be if I wanted to pass the value returned by `aPromiseReturningFunction` into the call to `$q.all`, correct? That is not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`then()` expects a function to be passed to it. You're currently passing another Promise object in here

`then($q.all(val.arrayProperty.map(function(anotherVal)`

You should instead be doing this

```
function nestedPromise(val) {
    return aPromiseReturningFunction(val)
      .then(function() {
        return $q.all(val.arrayProperty.map(function(anotherVal) {
          return anotherPromiseReturningFunction({
            prop1: anotherVal.prop
          });
        })
      });
}
```

Comment: Looks, promising! I can't test it out right now. Will report back ASAP. Much thanks for the answer!

Comment: This definitely works. However, if I break the anonymous function inside `then` out into a separate function, it stops working. Why would that be? Also, do you have any insight into the promises in `$q.all` don't stop running when the first rejection is encountered?

Comment: You can break the anonymous function into a separate function as long as it returns a `Promise`. As far as `$q.all()` stopping in the first rejection, this is by design, it either waits for all the promises to resolve or it rejects if ANY rejection occurs during the execution.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. If I copy and paste the anonymous function into a separate function (the return value of which is `$q.all`), it stops working, that is to say the return value of `nestedPromise` is resolved. Here's a concise version of the code snippet: `.then(addAnother(val))`, `function addAnother(val) { return $q.all(...); }`. For my second question, I am not asking why it rejects if only a single child promise rejects. I am asking why it continues to run the remaining promises after encountering the first rejection.

Comment: Could you provide a gist or a codepen, it would be more helpful to see what your code actually looks like.

Comment: Okay - vis-a-vis the first question, I got it figured out. Actually, I'm still a little worried that I might have some fundamental misunderstandings and that I don't actually "got it figured out", so if you could vet what I'm about to say, I'd appreciate that. In order to get `$q.all` working in a non-anonymous function, I had to make use of `$q.defer`. Your answer to my second question still indicates misunderstanding, but was very helpful nonetheless! I assumed that once the first promise rejected, no subsequent `then`s would be executed. I did not realize I needed a `catch` in the chain!

Comment: Let me try to be very clear about the second question. **Foundation**: `$q.all` takes an array of promises. **Expectation**: as soon as one promise in the array rejects, no subsequent promises in said array will attempt to be resolved and the promise returned by `$q.all` will indicate rejection. **Actual**: all promises in the array passed to `$q.all` will attempt to be resolved, regardless of how many of them reject. However, if at least one promise in the array rejects, the promise returned by `$q.all` will indicate rejection.